проблема с js графиком - всегда одно и тоже время по часу
вот код
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
console.log('New connection');
let userDataValue; // Переменная для хранения значения пользователя
let userDataTime; // Переменная для хранения времени пользователя

const sessionId = socket.id;

socket.emit('initialData', {newDataData, newDataLabel});

// Проверяем, запущен ли интервал
if (!isIntervalRunning) {
    interval = setInterval(() => {
        const newValue = generateRandomChange();
        newDataData.push(newValue.toFixed(2));
        newDataLabel.push(new Date());

        if (newDataData.length > MAX_DATA_POINTS) {
            newDataData.shift();
            newDataLabel.shift();
        }

        io.emit('newData', {newDataData, newDataLabel});
    }, 1000);

    isIntervalRunning = true;
}.......

newDataLabel всегда 20 часов https://i.sstatic.net/1KIckLu3.png скрин

В чём состоит вопрос?

newDataLabel.push(new Date()); в new Date() вроде все ok но на графику всегда 20 часов

Если в new Date() всё ОК, то вы просто смотрите на чужие данные, не те что посылаете в сокет.
